# Is there any way of create or altering VS Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I have recently installed Reshaper....this is very good and helpful however it has changed all my keyboard shortcuts e.g. to comment out code it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd>, now it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd> ... this is a pain given that I have got myself into a natural swing of using all the shortcuts and now I have to think everytime I want to use them...

A solution is obviously to shut up and use the new shortcuts ... I agree, but its unnecessary to change the way I work if a alteration solution is possible - so therefore its necessary to not change.

Comment: @Kendrick is right - 12 questions and no acceptances is pretty bad.

Comment: Ive tried going into Tools->Options->keyboard and changing it directly here, however reshaper is still god in this instance.

Comment: ...you two are the only two to have complained about this so far, I still get many people posting to my questions regardless....some people just want to code regardless of the status' that this site imposes upon questions and answers.

Look below....many answers :)

Comment: @urema - nevertheless, it is polite to accept answers if they are correct and helpful. The people that answer your questions have put their own time and effort into crafting answers for you; sheer courtesy dictates that you ought to accept answers where you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Resharper to use the VS shortcuts instead. At least for those you already know, they will stay the same

Comment: yes initially when you install resharper and restart VS yes....however I didnt pay attention here and applied all resharper ones....I was just curious about a method to change the the shortcuts anyway.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

@Mike mentions the Tools, Customize, Keyboard button. There's a 'Reset' button in there that will take you to a pre-Resharper state.

If you later want to go back to the Resharper shortcuts, you can use a button in Resharper's own Options dialog to apply them.

Comment: I think this resetting method would be appropriate, then I can any that shortcuts that I may need for resharper.

Thanks greatly, didnt even see the reset button!

U.

Answer (score 1):

Select ReSharper menu -> Options -> Visual Studio Integration: Select None and Apply Scheme. However, I highly recommend you pick one of the two keyboard layouts and learn it. Also, unplug the mouse a couple of hours a day. It helps improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible.  Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576362.aspx) on how to alter keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the link it was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just go to Tools->Customize and click the "Keyboard" button in the bottom left.

Comment: Relates to Tims reply above, but yes thanks I will use this approach.

U.

Answer (score 0):

During installation of *ReSharper* you can set whether it uses its own shortcut keys or *Visual Studio*. Moreover, there is an option in *ReSharper* to associate/dis-associate the keyboard shortcuts after installation.